# How to snap an object to another object's edge

Tags: objects, transforms, snapping

## How to snap an object to another object's edge.

I'm trying to find a more accurate way to place this object so that the edges are touching. I want to do this so that in my next step I can perform a boolean operation more smoothly.

[image]

I'm trying to get it to snap to the place where I'm circling it with the mouse.

I've tried googling and searching this site as well as the blender manual.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm really new to blender and trying to learn a good workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## When you use snap to edge the mouse has to actually touch what you want to snap to.

1. Click on the magnet to enable snapping.
2. Click on the option for snap to edge.
3. Move the object but **make sure the mouse touches what you want it to snap to.**

Animated gif for future reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Change the snapping mode in the snap tab in the 3d view header to **Vertex** and drag according on your specific axis until a small ring appears on the vertex you want to snap to when you hover the mouse over it.

Comment: It should have been edge, not vertex. However, that part about the mouse having to hover over it was what helped me figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Vertex snapping is better than edge snapping in some cases. In your case it fit the description. If your edge is non symmetrical or not parallel, you cant snap to its normal.

Comment: I didn't have a vertex in that area though so it didn't really work in my case. But the info is still valuable.

Comment: Yes there is, at the end points of the edge there are two Vertex, you can snap to either.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just didn't have the mouse hovering over that vertex! Thanks now I know :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a vertex to both the anvil's and cylinder's edge. 
Line them up at same height by eye 
Snap vertex to vertex.
Remove extra vertices.

(Probably not the ideal solution.)

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to answer the question myself without having to add extra vertices. :)

Comment: Nice. I actually never noticed that my mouse had to touch the geometry while using snap-to-x. Cool observation.

Answer (score 0):

I still think Blender needs some work in the snapping department. As you can see in @LateralTerminal's answer, Blender chooses which part of that oval should snap to the anvil. I think a better option would be to select "snapping" vertices in object 1 and 2 (outside of edit mode): the vertex to snap from then the vertex to snap to.

There's a nice feature in Fusion 360 called "Move - point to point": You select the start point then an end point - the two object snap together at exactly those two points.

I just don't get why Blender would make the decision about which part of the first object should do the snapping. I'm currently dealing with an object that snaps *away* from the target object when I hover the mouse over the target object.

Comment: Snapping and precision modelling will be updated and it was announced recently as the development fund has enough to pay for the dev. There is a discussion here https://devtalk.blender.org/t/discussions-for-better-snapping-and-precision-modeling-to-come/5351/10

Comment: @barkest Now that's what I'm talking about.